# $ A\setminus(B\setminus C) = (A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap C) $ how to prove?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

how to prove that:
$$
A\setminus(B\setminus C) = (A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap C)
$$

My attempts: $$A∖(B∖C) = x∈A ∧ x∉B (A∖B)∪(A∩C) = (x∈A ∧ x∉B) ∨ (x∈A ∧ x∈C)$$ im new in this, and im pretty stuck here

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Comment: i want to prove that these are equal

Comment: @Sushi We know what you want to do. That's obvious from reading your question post. We are asking what you have tried, because that's not obvious from your question post. You went through the trouble of signing up here just to ask this question, that can't have been the _first_ thing you tried. What did you try before you came here?

Comment: @Sushi I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show us your trying.

Comment: A∖(B∖C) = x∈A ∧ x∉B
(A∖B)∪(A∩C) = (x∈A ∧ x∉B) ∨ (x∈A ∧ x∈C)
im new in this, and im pretty stuck here

Comment: Thank you, @Sushi ! I posted my solution. You can see.

Comment: Thank you @Michael Rozenberg

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$$x\in A\setminus(B\setminus C)\Leftrightarrow x\in A\wedge x\not\in(B\setminus C)\Leftrightarrow x\in A\wedge\overline{x\in B\wedge x\not\in C}\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x\in A\wedge(x\not\in B\vee x\in C)\Leftrightarrow x\in(A\setminus B)\vee x\in(A\cap B)\Leftrightarrow x\in(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B).$$